# PHP syntax error, unexpected end of file on my Yii2 run on php 7.2

Tags: php, yii2

Im sorry about the question seems again n again but, im really dont know what the hek is goin on..

in my PC its run normal but when goin to hosting show me error..

```
<?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model]) ?>
```

above line showing error syntax error, unexpected end of file in php 7.2

and here full code

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Mahasiswa */

$this->title = 'Bua Data Mahasiswa';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Mahasiswas', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="mahasiswa-create" style="margin-left: 100px;margin-right: 100px;">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <hr>
    <?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model]) ?>

</div>
```

I really dont know what happen here..

please you guys help me

thank you so much...

EDIT :

here full trace

```
ParseError
syntax error, unexpected end of file
1. in /home/u7796600/public_html/views/mahasiswa/_form.phpat line 152
143144145146147148149150151    });
 
    JS;
 
    $this->registerJs($script,
        yii\web\View::POS_END,
        'in-x-handler'
    );?>
</div>
2. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 257– yii\base\View::renderPhpFile('/home/u7796600/public_html/views...', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa])
3. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 156– yii\base\View::renderFile('/home/u7796600/public_html/views...', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa], null)
4. in /home/u7796600/public_html/views/mahasiswa/create.php at line 16– yii\base\View::render('_form', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa])
101112131415161718$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="mahasiswa-create" style="margin-left: 100px;margin-right: 100px;">
 
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <hr>
    <?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model]) ?>
 
</div>
5. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 348– require('/home/u7796600/public_html/views...')
6. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 257– yii\base\View::renderPhpFile('/home/u7796600/public_html/views...', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa])
7. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php at line 156– yii\base\View::renderFile('/home/u7796600/public_html/views...', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa], app\controllers\MahasiswaController)
8. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 409– yii\base\View::render('create', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa], app\controllers\MahasiswaController)
9. in /home/u7796600/public_html/controllers/MahasiswaController.php at line 106– yii\base\Controller::render('create', ['model' => app\models\Mahasiswa])
100101102103104105106107108109110111112                    $model->addError('foto', "Foto tidak boleh kosong !");
                }
            }
        }
 
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
 
    /**
     * Updates an existing Mahasiswa model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
10. app\controllers\MahasiswaController::actionCreate()
11. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php at line 57– call_user_func_array([app\controllers\MahasiswaController, 'actionCreate'], [])
12. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php at line 180– yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams([])
13. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php at line 528– yii\base\Controller::runAction('create', [])
14. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php at line 103– yii\base\Module::runAction('mahasiswa/create', [])
15. in /home/u7796600/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php at line 386– yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
16. in /home/u7796600/public_html/index.php at line 12– yii\base\Application::run()
6789101112 
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
 
$config = require __DIR__ . '/config/web.php';
 
(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
$_COOKIE = [
    '_csrf' => '88604fb700879268611516c1ee39de9cdab11ea7f454885b6bf3328fb9d26e97a:2:{i:0;s:5:"_csrf";i:1;s:32:"bNGjdI0AfMr2cromPF1xm1f7RthBqbIf";}',
    '_identity-admin-simpresensi' => '["admin","jKDGomSH1sCM3KRg2zooF97hI6MbsNHN",2592000]',
    'PHPSESSID' => '021088dcd0c061b02965e21ab8d87fcb',
];

$_SESSION = [
    '__flash' => [],
    'admin' => 'admin',
];
```

My _form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Prodi;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use kartik\file\FileInput;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Mahasiswa */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="mahasiswa-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ; ?>
    <?php 
    $img = empty($model->foto) ? '':\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/images/' . $model->gambar;
    echo FileInput::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'foto',
        'options'=>[
            'accept'=>'image/*',
            'multiple'=>false
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'initialPreview'=>empty($model->foto) ? '':'<img width="158" src="'.$img.'" class="file-preview-image">',
            'initialCaption'=>"Foto",  
            'initialPreviewShowDelete' => false,
            'overwriteInitial' => true,
            'showPreview' => true,
            'showRemove' => false,
            'showUpload' => false,
            'maxFileSize'=>2800
        ],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'fileuploaded'=>"function(event, data, previewId, index){
                console.log(data);
            }",
        ]
    ]);    
    ?>
    <br>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'nim')->textInput() ?>
    
    <?=$form->field($model, 'id_prodi')
        ->dropDownList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Prodi::find()->all(), 'id', 'nama'),
        ['prompt' => 'Pilih Prodi']
    )?>


    <?=$form->field($model, 'tahun_masuk')
        ->dropDownList(
        [
            '2010' => '2010',
            '2011' => '2011',
            '2012' => '2012',
            '2013' => '2013',
            '2014' => '2014',
            '2015' => '2015',
            '2016' => '2016',
            '2017' => '2017',
            '2018' => '2018',
            '2019' => '2019',
            '2020' => '2020',
            '2021' => '2021',
        ],
        ['prompt' => 'Pilih Tahun Masuk']
    )?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'nama')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'jenis_kelamin')
        ->dropDownList(
        [
            'Laki-laki' => 'Laki-laki',
            'Perempuan' => 'Perempuan'
        ],
        ['prompt' => 'Pilih Jenis Kelamin']
    )?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tempat_lahir')->textArea(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'tanggal_lahir')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Pilih Tanggal Lahir ...'],
        'convertFormat' => true,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'autoclose'=>true,
        ]
    ]) ?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'agama')
        ->dropDownList(
            [
                'Islam' => 'Islam',
                'Kristen' => 'Kristen',
                'Katolik' => 'Katolik',
                'Hindu' => 'Hindu',
                'Budha' => 'Budha',
                'Konghuchu' => 'Konghuchu',
                'Kepercayaan' => 'Kepercayaan',
            ],
        ['prompt' => 'Pilih Agama']
    )?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'alamat_rumah')->textArea(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'domisili')->textArea(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?=$form->field($model, 'akses')
        ->dropDownList(
            [
                0 => 'Tidak',
                1 => 'Ya',
            ],
            ['prompt' => 'Pilih Akses Aplikasi'],
    )?>
    <div id='psd'>            
        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Simpan', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    <?php
    $script = <<< JS

    $('#mahasiswa-akses').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById("psd").style.display= val == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    });

    $(function(){        
        console.log(document.getElementById('mahasiswa-akses').value);
        document.getElementById("psd").style.display= document.getElementById("mahasiswa-akses").value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    });

    JS;

    $this->registerJs($script,
        yii\web\View::POS_END,
        'in-x-handler'
    );?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your `_form` view file.

Comment: `JS;` needs to be at the start of the line, there must be no whitespace before it, otherwise it does not get regonized as the end of the heredoc block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your heredoc declaration in `_form.php` is wrong. There shouldn't be a space between `<<<` and identifier at the start. The line for ending heredoc can contain only identifier and semicolon that means the identifier at the end of heredoc **must not be indented**.

Because you have the identifier indented the parser doesn't recognize it as end of heredoc declaration and parses the rest of file as string. Then when it comes to end it's complaining that it hadn't found the end of heredoc before the end of file.

This is how your heredoc declaration in `_form.php` should look like:

```php
    <?php
    $script = <<<JS
    $('#mahasiswa-akses').on('change', function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        document.getElementById("psd").style.display= val == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    });

    $(function(){        
        console.log(document.getElementById('mahasiswa-akses').value);
        document.getElementById("psd").style.display= document.getElementById("mahasiswa-akses").value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
JS;

    $this->registerJs($script,
        yii\web\View::POS_END,
        'in-x-handler'
    );?>
```

You can find some examples of heredoc declaration [in php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Also another thing that might cause problem if you are developing the script on windows machine than upload it to the linux/unix server is the character for end of line. The end of heredoc must be preceeded and followed by end of line character the current system is using. Windows uses `\r\n` as end of line but linux/unix systems uses only `\n` character.
So if you've developed the script on windows machine the end of your heredocs looks like:

```
JS;
```

But in linux/unix systems only `\n` is treated as new line and `\r` is left in string. That breaks the rule that only identifier and semicolon might be present in the end of heredoc.

```
\r
JS;\r
```

If you upload your scripts to server via FTP make sure you use `text` transfer for php files. The `text` transfer will convert the end of lines for you.
If you are using some versioning system like git there should be some settings that will allow you to convert the end of lines when commiting at your dev machine or pulling at your server.
Or you can set your editor to save files with unix style end of lines.

NOTE:
This requirements for heredoc are valid up to php 7.2.x. As noted by **rob006** in comments the php 7.3 brought more flexible heredoc syntax that allows indentation and doesn't require `;` and newline character right after ending identifier. But indentation still have its special meaning and can't be longer than identation of any line in the heredoc string. [More details about heredoc/nowdoc changes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/flexible_heredoc_nowdoc_syntaxes).

Comment: *identifier at the end of heredoc must not be indented* - that has been changed since PHP 7.3: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/flexible_heredoc_nowdoc_syntaxes

Comment: @rob006 thanks, you are right, i've added the note to the end of my answer. But original question was about php 7.2 where the limitations still apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I spent all morning trying to work out why it was breaking upon deploying on AWS EC2 and it drives me so mad that it was because of difference in support for heredocs. My local PHP is newer, so it doesn't complain about indentation at all.